# Show InlineModelAdmin for nested Model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have nested models with OneToOneFields and want to have an InlineModelAdmin form in one ModelAdmin to point to a nested model...

`models.py:`

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    password = models.charField(max_length=128)

class IdentityProof(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='proof')
    proof_identity = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')

class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='company')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='person')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

`admin.py:`

```
class IdentityProofInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IdentityProof

@admin.register(Company)
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [IdentityProofInline]

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [IdentityProofInline]
```

For CompanyAdmin or PersonAdmin, I want to show its User's IdentityProof. How can I do that ?

I tried to use `fk_name = 'user_proof` or other combinations but it doesn't work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without an external package.
See [Django Nested Inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) and [Django Nested Admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin)